# Validation against XSD ignores duplicate keys in XML-file

Tags: xml, xsd, key, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate XML-files against [this schema](http://www.aed.public.lu/FAIA/FAIA/FAIA_v_2_01_full.xsd).

There is a master table section which contatins data that is then referenced from elsewhere in the file. The MasterFile Table is supposed to contain unique entries, so that they can be referenced from elsewhere in the xml-file.

However I am unable to get it to recognize what ought to be invalid keys. I have tried validating in XML Notepad, Notepad++ using XML Tools and Eclipse.

Definition of TaxTable from above schem:

```
<xs:element name="TaxTable" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TaxTableEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TaxType" type="FAIAcodeType">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Description" type="FAIAlongtextType">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="TaxCodeDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="TaxCode" type="FAIAcodeType">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="EffectiveDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="ExpirationDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="Description" type="FAIAlongtextType" minOccurs="0">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:element name="TaxPercentage" type="xs:decimal">
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="FlatTaxRate" type="AmountStructure">
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:choice>
                                    <xs:element name="Country" type="ISOCountryCode">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="Region" type="FAIAcodeType" minOccurs="0">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Key and KeyRef definitions:

```
<xs:key name="KeyTaxType">
<xs:selector xpath="MasterFiles/TaxTable/TaxTableEntry"/>
<xs:field xpath="TaxType"/>
</xs:key>

<xs:keyref name="RefRegistrationTaxType" refer="KeyTaxType">
<xs:selector xpath="Header/Company/TaxRegistration"/>
<xs:field xpath="TaxType"/>
</xs:keyref>

<xs:keyref name="RefCustomerTaxType" refer="KeyTaxType">
<xs:selector xpath="MasterFiles/Customers/Customer/TaxRegistration"/>
<xs:field xpath="TaxType"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Example of minimal xml-file that ought to break the TaxType key restraint, but which validates in 3 different tools. Validation works for everything except keys, as I get errors when I add a non-existing element or changes the order of elements in a squence, so I can see that validation takes place at least.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:AuditFile
xmlns:xs="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00 ../../main/resources/FAIA_v_2_01_full.xsd ">
<xs:Header>
    <xs:AuditFileVersion>2.0.1</xs:AuditFileVersion>
    <xs:AuditFileCountry>LU</xs:AuditFileCountry>
    <xs:AuditFileDateCreated>2001-01-01</xs:AuditFileDateCreated>
    <xs:SoftwareCompanyName>TestCorp</xs:SoftwareCompanyName>
    <xs:SoftwareID>Test</xs:SoftwareID>
    <xs:SoftwareVersion>Test</xs:SoftwareVersion>
    <xs:Company>
        <xs:RegistrationNumber>123456</xs:RegistrationNumber>
        <xs:Name>Test Corporation</xs:Name>
        <xs:Address>
            <xs:City>London</xs:City>
            <xs:PostalCode>123456</xs:PostalCode>
        </xs:Address>
        <xs:Contact>
            <xs:ContactPerson>
                <xs:FirstName>John</xs:FirstName>
                <xs:LastName>Doe</xs:LastName>
            </xs:ContactPerson>
            <xs:Telephone>45646825</xs:Telephone>
        </xs:Contact>
        <xs:TaxRegistration>
            <xs:TaxRegistrationNumber>LU1234566-78</xs:TaxRegistrationNumber>
            <xs:TaxType>TVA</xs:TaxType>
            <xs:TaxNumber>LU1234566-78</xs:TaxNumber>
        </xs:TaxRegistration>
    </xs:Company>
    <xs:DefaultCurrencyCode>EUR</xs:DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <xs:SelectionCriteria>
        <xs:TaxReportingJurisdiction>xs:TaxReportingJurisdiction</xs:TaxReportingJurisdiction>
        <xs:CompanyEntity>xs:CompanyEntity</xs:CompanyEntity>
        <xs:SelectionStartDate>2015-01-01</xs:SelectionStartDate>
        <xs:SelectionEndDate>2015-12-31</xs:SelectionEndDate>
        <xs:DocumentType>xs:DocumentType</xs:DocumentType>
        <xs:OtherCriteria>First Other Criteria</xs:OtherCriteria>
        <xs:OtherCriteria>Second Other Criteria</xs:OtherCriteria>
    </xs:SelectionCriteria>
    <xs:HeaderComment>xs:HeaderComment</xs:HeaderComment>
    <xs:TaxAccountingBasis>Invoice Accounting</xs:TaxAccountingBasis>
    <xs:TaxEntity>xs:TaxEntity</xs:TaxEntity>
</xs:Header>
<xs:MasterFiles>
<xs:TaxTable>
    <xs:TaxTableEntry>
        <xs:TaxType>TVA</xs:TaxType>
        <xs:Description>Taxe sur la valeur ajoutée</xs:Description>
        <xs:TaxCodeDetails>
            <xs:TaxCode>1</xs:TaxCode>
            <xs:EffectiveDate>2010-01-01</xs:EffectiveDate>
            <xs:Description>LU/01/0/0.00 - TVA sur ventes</xs:Description>
            <xs:TaxPercentage>0.0</xs:TaxPercentage>
            <xs:Country>LU</xs:Country>
        </xs:TaxCodeDetails>
    </xs:TaxTableEntry>
    <xs:TaxTableEntry>
        <xs:TaxType>TVA</xs:TaxType>
        <xs:Description>Taxe sur la valeur ajoutée</xs:Description>
        <xs:TaxCodeDetails>
            <xs:TaxCode>1</xs:TaxCode>
            <xs:EffectiveDate>2010-01-01</xs:EffectiveDate>
            <xs:Description>LU/01/0/0.00 - TVA sur ventes</xs:Description>
            <xs:TaxPercentage>0.0</xs:TaxPercentage>
            <xs:Country>LU</xs:Country>
        </xs:TaxCodeDetails>
    </xs:TaxTableEntry>
</xs:TaxTable>
</xs:MasterFiles>
```

Updated to show that it seems to be a validation problem.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is different from what you describe.

In short, the `selector` selects **what** elements need to be unique, and the `field` selects what **makes them unique**.

In this case, the selector selects the entire list of `TaxTableEntry`s, and for each of those, the field selects its `TaxType`. Concretely, this means that within this list (that is, not within each item of the list, but within the whole list), the `TaxType`s must be all different.

With the `keyRef`s, these values can be referenced as foreign keys to unambiguously identify a `TaxTableEntry` within a `MasterFile` (or wherever you place the `key` definition).

If the behaviour of validation on your side deviates from this, feel free to share an XML instance that behaves differently from what you expect and we can help further.

Comment: I also assumed that was how it worked, or at least how the creator of the schema wanted it to have worked. I edited my post and added an example that validates with duplicate `TaxType`s.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it may be because of namespace bindings. Could you paste the namespace bindings from the schema files? (Everything that looks like `xmlns`). Thanks!

Comment: Some results when googling suggested this could be the source of the problem.

Is this what you had in mind?

`<xs:schema xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:doc="urn:schemas-OECD:schema-extensions:documentation" targetNamespace="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.00" id="FAIA-T">`